# How to import from backup MySql 8.0 to master-to-master replication

Tags: mysql, replication

replication with step = 2 - one node use AUTO_INCREMENT with even numbers, second one is odd numbers

What would be right sequence?
'''

1. STOP REPLICA;  // on both nodes
2. source c:/dump.sql // only one onde node?
3. ALTER TABLE every_table AUTO_INCREMENT = maxVal + 1 // need for second node?
4. master reset  //  for second node too?
5. start replica; // both nodes
6. show replica status // both nodes
   '''

Answer (score 0):

Instead of step 4:

4.a on node1: add to the end of my.ini

```
auto_increment_increment=2
auto_increment_offset=2

[mysqld]
server-id=2
log-bin=mysql-bin
relay-log=node2-relay-bin
net_read_timeout = 3600
net_write_timeout = 3600
```

4.b on node2: add to the end of my.ini

```
auto_increment_increment=2
auto_increment_offset=2

[mysqld]
server-id=2
log-bin=mysql-bin
relay-log=node2-relay-bin
net_read_timeout = 3600
net_write_timeout = 3600
```

restart service

on both nodes:

4.c. Reseeding Primary Keys:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE ResetAutoIncrementForAllTables()
BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE tblName CHAR(255);
    DECLARE maxVal BIGINT;
    
    -- Declare a cursor to select table names
    DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT TABLE_NAME 
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
        WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE() AND TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE';
    
    -- Handler for the cursor
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;
    
    OPEN cur;
    
    tableLoop: LOOP
        FETCH cur INTO tblName;
        IF done THEN
            LEAVE tableLoop;
        END IF;
        
        -- Fetch the max value from the table
        SET @maxQuery = CONCAT('SELECT IFNULL(MAX(`AUTO_INCREMENT`), 0) + 1 INTO @maxVal FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = "', DATABASE(), '" AND TABLE_NAME = "', tblName, '"');
        PREPARE maxStmt FROM @maxQuery;
        EXECUTE maxStmt;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE maxStmt;
        
        -- Set the new auto-increment value
        SET @alterQuery = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ', tblName, ' AUTO_INCREMENT = ', @maxVal);
        PREPARE alterStmt FROM @alterQuery;
        EXECUTE alterStmt;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE alterStmt;
    END LOOP;
    
    CLOSE cur;
END //
DELIMITER ;

call ResetAutoIncrementForAllTables();
```

4d.  on node2: SHOW MASTER STATUS;
on node1:
fill file name and offset into:

```
CHANGE REPLICATION SOURCE TO 
     SOURCE_HOST='node2.stackoverflow.com',
     SOURCE_USER='replicator',
     SOURCE_PASSWORD='password',
     SOURCE_LOG_FILE='mysql-bin.000001',
     SOURCE_LOG_POS=598773191;
```

4e.  on node1: SHOW MASTER STATUS;
on node2:
fill file name and offset into:

```
CHANGE REPLICATION SOURCE TO 
     SOURCE_HOST='node1.stackoverflow.com',
     SOURCE_USER='replicator',
     SOURCE_PASSWORD='password',
     SOURCE_LOG_FILE='mysql-bin.000001',
     SOURCE_LOG_POS=598773191;
```

4f: on both nodes

START REPLICA;